# Prioritizing a Task in high concurrent image processing (prevent stacking)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

Is there an option in C# to give a priority for Tasks that ran first. I am using a code for image processing. In my testing and in high workload (e.g. 100 concurrent parallel image processing and uploading), when I run the tasks in parallel without any waiting (e.g. Thread.sleep(1000), the upload stacks up and the almost all the images are sent after most of the images have been uploaded.

I want to give priority to images that enter first to get out as fast as possible. In high load I see that I need to wait a long time until I see the first image getting out.

Comment: Use only a small, fixed-size threadpool for the actual uploading, so that later images have to queue up?

Comment: Most of the time, if you need to prioritize tasks/threads then you have a design problem.

Comment: @L.B Can you explain problem. I am running image processing tasks in parallel. I obviously need more CPU power to process more, but that's how the CPU handle the processing and that leads to the result I described.

Comment: @IdanShechter to be able to comment on the problem, you should post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) `I am running image processing tasks in parallel` doesn't  mean much because there are many different ways to accomplish this.

Comment: @L.B.  I am looking into it..

Comment: Try a consumer producer like a blocking collection.  I do exactly that  where I read in some text files in the producer and the parse out words in the the consumer.  You can have a max size so the producer does not get too far ahead of the consumer.  Upload may not benefit from parallel.